# Spring dependency injection with interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm not quite sure if I should use constructor injection or field injection. I feel like I should do field injection, but that leads me to wondering a proper way of deciding how to determine which implementation to use.

I have created a interface that I consider a Repository:

```
public interface Repository {
    public Map<String, String> loadData(InputStream file, FileProperties fileProperties);
    public String getData(String filename);
}
```

In my RestController, I want to check an environment variable to see which implementation of this interface I am going to use.

I noticed I can do constructor injection with the two implementations, which would leave me with something like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/files")
public class RespositoryAPI {
   private Repository repository;
   private final String MODE_TYPE = System.getenv(ENV_MODE);

   public RepositoryAPI(RepoImplA a, RepoImplB b) {
      if (MODE_TYPE == "A") {
         repository = a;
      }
      ...
   }

     @PostMapping
     public Map<String, String> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("properties") FileProperties properties) {
        return repository.loadData(file.getInputStream(), properties);
     }

}
```

Essentially as new viable implementations come through, I imagine I would need to add them to the constructor like so:

```
public RepositoryAPI(ImplA a, ImplB b, ImplC c, ...)
```

The alternative way I understand is to use Spring @Autowired like so:

```
    @Autowired
    private RepoImplA a;

    @Autowired
    private RepoImplB b;
```

If I do this, I don't know a good way of deciding which one of the implementations to actually use, based on that env variable.

Maybe I'm making this a little more complicated than it needs to be. What would be the proper way to go about this?

Comment: I'm not in a position to play with this right now, but I believe that your answer might be to use a `@Bean` annotation on a factory method that returns a `Repository`. You can test in that method to decide which impl to create and create the right one with `new`.  The key thing is that you have to cause a `BeanFactory` to call that method to get you an instance of `Repository`...you can't call the factory method yourself, or the result won't get wired by Spring.  For example, you could `@Autowire` or constructor inject a `Repository` into another bean and get the result of that factory method.

Comment: I agree with @CryptoFool, `RepositoryAPI` (not a great class name, I'd name it `RepositoryResource`) should not care about the rules for choosing the `Repository` implementation.

Comment: You can use spring profiles to choose which beans are instantiated at run time.

Comment: Always use constructor injection over field injection, and as described, select which bean upstream (through one of several mechanisms).

Comment: Agree with Hopey and Chrylis. But if you REALLY want to select the right beam using code and not configuration (not ideal) then it's better if you have all RepoImpl's implement a common interface which has a "getMode" on it and then add to the constructor a list/collection of objects of that common interface to select the one you want to use in the constructor by filtering the list of objects yourself at construct time.

Comment: @Atmas so what you and Chrylis are suggesting is try and use profiles and let spring determine which impl to use?

Comment: If your design always chooses one correct impl at bean factory (spring) startup then yes you should direct spring to satisfy it with the right one one i.e. with profiles. If you need several impls and you need to pick one based on criteria only knowable at runtime then get fancier (factories, getModes etc.)

Comment: @Atmas Is this a valid reason to use spring profiles? Every time I lookin up spring profiles it mentions dev/test/prod, things like that.

Comment: Without knowing why and how you are using multiple implementations in it's hard for me/us to answer whether you are using it correctly. But if you feel it's an ill fit then it's best to research further before proceeding.